# Python Wait for a return of a function?

Tags: python, function, game-development

maybe this title of my question is a little bit confusing. The reason is that I have no idea to solve my problem. Maybe with multiprocessing, threading, await/async or something else?
I don’t know much about this topics, and I hope some of you know how I can get closer to the solution. 
To my project: 
I’m developing a chess-game in python (maybe not the best language but accept it xD). Here is the structure of main.py:

```
from figures import *
from board import *
#init all figures with OOP
while True:
     INPUT = input
     #proof input and do some calculation stuff
     #if you can make the move with for example Queen
            board = refresh_board() #the methode can access all new positions and the old board and return the new board
            print(board) #later: visualize/refresh visual board
```

In the files figures are the figures with the different ways to move defined. The board.py is for the refresh and access of the board. 
The board looks in the first Round like this:

```
[[-2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -4 -3 -2]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1]
 [ 2  3  4  5  6  4  3  2]]
```

Now my question. I want to visualize this “board”. I got pictures of the board and figures, but the problem is how can show/let the window open and update it after the user did an input? And with which library can I do the visualization (the only library with pictures that I thought of was cv2).

Comment: do you want something like the input function? `input()` will allow you to wait for user input. Note that the wait will be indefinite, you should set a timeout if you want a user to input something within an allocated amount of time. Here is the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Comment: your title is totally missleading. You should rather ask ie. "how to display images in game"

Comment: the most popular (and probably the oldest) module for games in python is [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/docs/). There are also [pgzero](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), [arcade](https://api.arcade.academy/en/latest/), etc.  Or modules [pyglet](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), `PyOpenGL`. But you can also use any GUI framework - like `tkinter`, `PyQt`, `PySide`, `wxPython`, `PyGTK`, [kivy](https://kivy.org/#home), etc. It is strange that you didn't find any of them. Searching in Google `python game module` you should find many informations.